# Problem in understanding Operon

Tags: genetics, dna, book-recommendation, operons

Is there a good book that explains operons: lac operon and trp operon in details.

I was reading  the functioning of the trp repressor protein from 'Principles of genetics-by Snustard and Simmons',they have mentioned that the binding of the repressor-corepressor complex to O$_t$$_r$$_p$ prevents the transcription of the structural genes. But they don't explain how.

[Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/gene-regulation/gene-regulation-in-bacteria/a/the-trp-operon) says that the repressor-corepressor complex physically comes in the way of the RNA polymerase. They have used this diagram below which shows that the large RNA polymerase cannot bind to the promoter site due to steric hindrance.

[image]

I'm looking for a more authentic source to study exactly how this RNA polymerase is being prevented from transcribing the DNA in both the operons.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 31 in the Voet and Voet biochemistry book (I have the 4th edition) [link](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP001782.html) has a rather extensive explanation on this subject. It is rather pricey but you can find a copy of this one in nearly every university library. It generally is a good resource if you want to know more about the DNA or Protein structure of a basic process